# Can I get the email app to only download email headers -- and get bodies on demand? This is for an MS Exchange based email service

Tags: email

Can I get the email app to only download email headers -- and get bodies on demand?  This is for an MS Exchange based email service.  I have a Nexus One.  The email app works fine, but the volume of email I get for work is huge and although I need to see all the subject lines, I rarely need to read the full email when I'm not at work.  How can I get the email app to just download headers?  Alternatively, is there another email app in the Market I could use for this?

I have Android version 2.2.1

Comment: Which mail app?, I assume it's GMail client because you are using a Nexus, but there are lots of mail clients for android.

Comment: No.  The plain old Android email app.

Answer (score 2):

If I look at my settings for an Exchange server I have a 'Incoming size' under 'General settings' where I can specify 'Headers only'.

I am running Froyo 2.2.1 on Samsung Galaxy S.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Touchdown ($20):

http://www.nitrodesk.com/dk_touchdownFeatures.aspx

For the **Email Download Size** you can set **No Body**.